# Laravel resource destroy mtehode does not work

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have created a Product Resource Controller with `php artisan make:controller ProductController --resource`. And have all necessary methods: index, show, update and destroy.

I am using Laravel 8, the destroy method has by default Product $product as parameter ( Route Model Binding ).

Theoretically, I only have to take the product object and delete it? I also get back status code 200 and a true. Nevertheless, the entry is not deleted from the database.

**Note:** I change my Route Key Name to ID and my index Key Name to uid instead id. See migration and Model.

**Question:** Why? What im missing? Does it have anything to do with the changed route key name?

Here my ProductController, Model, Migration and Route:

**ProductController.php -> destroy() Method**

```
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Product $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $result = $product->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'status' => $result,
            'msg' => $result ? 'success' : 'failed'
        ]);        
    }
```

**Models\Product**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'ID',
        'name',
        'price',
    ];

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
      return 'ID';
    }    
}
```

**Product Migration up() Method**

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('uid'); // changed
            $table->integer('ID')->unique(); // my new Route Key Name
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->integer('price')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Route api.php**

```
Route::resource('products', App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $result = Post::where('ID', $id)->delete();
    return response()->json([
        'status' => $result,
        'msg' => $result ? 'success' : 'failed'
    ]);        
}
```

Comment: That would work. but I wanted to use the power of the Route Model binding? Because Laravel already puts it as a parameter of the destroy method. Is that possibly a bug?

Comment: Route model binding maybe only auto increment id.
This works if you use an id